# XSLT outputting text of nodes that should have be handled already

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a problem with my XSLT file, which takes an XML file on roughly the form:

```
<model>
    <interface>
        <doc>text1</doc>
        <acc>
            <op name="name">
                <in>
                    <doc>text2</doc>
                    <parameter name="name" type="type">
                        <doc>text3</doc>
                    </parameter>
                </in>
                <out>
                    <doc>text4</doc>
                    <parameter name="name" type="type">
                        <doc>text5</doc>
                    </parameter>
                </out>
                <exception name="name">
                    <doc>text6</doc>
                    <parameter name="name" type="type">
                        <doc>text7</doc>
                    </parameter>
                    <parameter name="name" type="type">
                        <doc>text8</doc>
                    </parameter>
                </exception>
            </op>
        </acc>
        <conn>
            <op name="name">
                <in>
                    <doc>text9</doc>
                    <parameter name="name" type="type">
                        <doc>text10</doc>
                    </parameter>
                </in>
            </op>
        </conn>
        <!-- rest omitted !-->
    </interface>
</model>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />


<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</xsl:text>
    <html>
    <head>
      <script>
      <!-- omitted !-->
    </script>
    <style>
      <!-- omitted !-->
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <table class="tablesorter" border="1">
      <thead>
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                <th style="text-align:left">Name</th>
            </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="//acc|//conn" mode="toc"/>     
      </tbody>
        </table>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//acc|//conn" mode="detail"/>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="create_detail_table">
  <b>Description:</b> <xsl:value-of select="doc"/>
  <h4>Parameters</h4>
  <table class="tablesorter" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="word-wrap:normal; width:30%">Name</th>
        <th style="word-wrap:normal; width:30%">Type</th>
        <th style="word-wrap:normal; width:30%">Description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="parameter"/>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="acc/op/in" mode="toc">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#{../@name}"><xsl:value-of select="../@name"/>foo</a></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="acc/op/in" mode="detail">
    <h3 id="{../@name}"><xsl:value-of select="../@name"/>foo</h3>
  <xsl:call-template name="create_detail_table"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="parameter">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@type"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="doc"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="acc/op/out" mode="detail">
    <h3><xsl:value-of select="../@name"/>foo</h3>
  <xsl:call-template name="create_detail_table"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="acc/op/exception" mode="detail">
  <h3><xsl:value-of select="../@name"/>bar</h3>
  <xsl:call-template name="create_detail_table"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="conn/op/in" mode="detail">
  <h3><xsl:value-of select="../@name"/>baz</h3>
  <xsl:call-template name="create_detail_table"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="model/interface/acc/op/in/parameter/doc" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My problem is that this output looks completely fine except for the fact that the outputted HTML outputs the text of `in/doc`, `out/doc`, `exception/doc` and all `parameter/doc` tags at the very top of the document (except for those under the first `in` tag, why?).

So basically the doc output is, at the top of the document (followed by other output that looks correct, with tables and stuff):

```
text4 text5 text6 text7 text8 text9 tex10
```

[image: Output of the above transformation]

Why would this happen? I know that this happens because of default templates, but it seems to me that I am not matching those tags anywhere. And in the event that I did, I added the final template at the bottom, matching `model/interface/acc/op/in/parameter/doc`, just to catch such a match, but it didn't help in any way.

I have also attempted to override the default templates that cause this behavior, such as:

```
<xsl:template match="text()" />
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="*" />
```

However, neither of these make a difference. I'm at a loss here.

P.S. Feel free to comment on my style of XSLT. I'm only just learning it and am curious if I'm following idiomatic XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `<xsl:apply-templates select="//acc|//conn" mode="toc"/>` but the only template for that mode `toc` is

```
<xsl:template match="acc/op/in" mode="toc">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#{../@name}"><xsl:value-of select="../@name"/>foo</a></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

If you only want to process the `acc/op/in` elements for that mode to output a table row then don't process other elements so the simplest fix seems to be to use `<xsl:apply-templates select="//acc/op/in" mode="toc"/>`.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, you are applying templates to the nodes that contain the text nodes being output, but you do not have corresponding templates that match them. In such situation, the [**built-in template rules**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#built-in-rule) will kick in - and their action is to output all descendant text values.

> I have also attempted to override the default templates that cause
>   this behavior, such as:
>
> `<xsl:template match="text()" />`

If this doesn't work, then apparrently the templates have been applied in a different mode. And indeed,

```
<xsl:template match="text()" mode="toc"/>
```

will suppress the unwanted text.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. However, accepting the other answer since it seems like a better idea.

Comment: Just to clarify, the idea is the same: apply your templates more selectively. I only added an explanation why **your** idea didn't work.